# How to trigger a certain event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

First of all sorry for the bad question, I don't know how to write it well in one sentence.

Here is my scenario, I am making a game where 3 pictures are displayed on screen and along with a word. These pictures and words have come from a database.

Data is entered into the database so for every word time a word is entered a picture is also uploaded with it.

All these sets of words and images are pulled from a database and put into a JavaScript array. I have then randomly chosen  3 images from an array and placed them in another array and then at random picked one word from the second array.

My question is how do you make the word I have chosen link with the correct image and then when the correct picture is clicked by the user something happens like "Well Done" comes on screen?

here is my array layout : -

```
   var items = [
          {name:'Coch',image:'upload/coch.png'},                                                                                   {name:'Glas',image:'upload/glas.png'},
     {name:'Melyn',image:'upload/melyn.png'},{name:'Ci',image:'upload/dog.jpg'},
      {name:'Cath',image:'upload/cath.jpg'},{name:'Gwyrdd',image:'upload/gwyrdd.png'},
     {name:'Un',image:'upload/un.jpg'},{name:'Dau',image:'upload/dau.jpg'},
     {name:'Tri',image:'upload/tri.jpg'},{name:'Bochdew',image:'upload/bochdew.jpg'},
     {name:'Piws',image:'upload/piws.png'}      ];
```

Here is my full code:-

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>

      <html lang="en">

             <div id="choosecat">
             <form method="get" action="playgame.php"       autocomplete="off">

                       <fieldset>
                          <legend>Choose Category</legend> 


                          <label>Category: <select name="topic">

                          <option value="%">All</option>
                           <option value="Animals">Animals</option>
                          <option value="Numbers">Numbers</option>
                          <option value="Colours">Colours</option>

                           </select></label>

                           <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Go" />

                      </fieldset>


                        <br />




                  </form>


                  <?php 

                    $topic = $_GET['topic'];

                   $topic_choice = htmlspecialchars($topic,  ENT_QUOTES);



                   ?>


                        </div>

        <head>
              <title></title>



        <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="red"
           href="gameplay.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="blue"
       href="theme1.css">

      <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="pink"
    href="theme2.css">

    <script src="js/stylesheets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


      <script>

   var items = [
      <?php
       $con = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","password");
      if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }
      mysql_select_db("learning_game", $con);
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE category LIKE '$topic_choice' ");
      $first = true;



      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if (!$first) {
          echo ",";
        }
        $first = false;
        echo "{name:'" . $row['word'] . "',image:'" . $row['image'] . "',video:'" .     $row['video'] . "',audio:'" . $row['audio'] . "'}";
    }
      mysql_close($con);
      ?>
     ];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {
        //document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML += items[i].name + " / " + items[i].image + "<br />\n";
        }  

           document.write("<br /> <br /> <br />");





    console.log(items);
    top.items = items;

        var images = new Array();
         var list = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
         var names = new Array()
        var videos= new Array()
        var audios= new Array()

             for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

          // Choose a random item and removes it from the array
            var item = items.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length), 1)[0];

           // Create the image element and set its src attribute
           images[i] = document.createElement('img');
          images[i].src = item.image;

          videos[i] = document.createElement('video');
          videos[i].src = item.video;
             //video.controls = true;


              audios[i] = document.createElement('audio');
             audios[i].src = item.audio;
             //audio.controls = true;

             // var audio = new Audio(video);



             // Add it to your container element

           images.src = item.image;
            videos.src = item.video;
        audios.src = item.audio;
        names[i] = item.name;




          }
         var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
          var name_to_display = names[randomIndex];
         var image_to_display = images[randomIndex];
        var video_to_display = videos[randomIndex];
        var audio_to_display = audios[randomIndex];


      var data = new Array();


   document.getElementById("one").appendChild(images[0]);
   document.getElementById("two").appendChild(images[1]);
   document.getElementById("three").appendChild(images[2]);


       document.body.appendChild(audio[0]);
  document.getElementById("whitebox").appendChild(video[1]);
   document.getElementById("whitebox").appendChild(video[2]);


    /*document.getElementById("one").appendChild(data.image[0]);
    document.getElementById("two").appendChild(data.image[1]);
     document.getElementById("three").appendChild(data.image[2]);
   */



          </script>

       </head>

       <body onload="set_style_from_cookie()">
        <div id="container">




            <div id="header">
                <br />
                <img id="mabon" src="mabon.png"/>

            </div>

                       <div id="radio">
                          <input class="centerradio" type="checkbox"  name="theme" onclick="switch_style('red');return false;" value="Main">Mabon A Mabli
                            <input id="top_radio_button" class="centerradio" type="checkbox" name="theme" onclick="switch_style('blue');return false;" value="Blue Theme">Pastel <br>
                          <input class="centerradio" type="checkbox" name="theme" onclick="switch_style('pink');return false;" value="Pink Theme">Plain<br />
                       </div>

                     <div id="change_cat">




           <div id="random">


           <div class="wrapper">
               <div id="one" class="item"></div>

             <div id="two" class="item"></div>

               <div id="three" class="item"></div>

          </div>


          <div id="wordwrapper">

              <div id="worddiv">

                  <p id="wordtext"><script>document.write('-- '+name_to_display+' --');</script></p>

             </div>



          </div>


       <div id="videocorner">
        Video Corner
       </div>   

       <div id="videodiv">
          <video width="300" height="230" controls>
               <source src="bbc_three.mp4" type="video/mp4">
               <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
               Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
      </div>




      <div id="linkdiv">
               <a href="#" id="link" class="myButton">Makaton</a>
          </div>




              <div id="sounddiv">
      <!--
    <audio autoplay="3" controls>
      <source src="hover.wav" type="audio/wav">
     <source src="hover.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
        -->




     </div> 
       <img src="cartoon.png" id="help" height="200px">
     </div>     











      <div id="whitebox">
        <script>

            </script>
      </div>


          <div id="disp">

       <script>
         var audio = document.createElement('audio');
               audio.src = audio_to_display.src;
         //audio.src = item.audio;
         audio.controls = true;
         document.getElementById("disp").appendChild(audio);
     </script>



      <script>
                document.getElementById("one").appendChild(images[0]);
          document.getElementById("two").appendChild(images[1]);
         document.getElementById("three").appendChild(images[2]);


         var video = document.createElement('video');
         video.src = video_to_display.src;
         //video.src = item.video;
         video.controls = true;
         document.getElementById("disp").appendChild(video);
        </script>

          </div>

        </body>
     </html>
```

Sorry for the quality of the code, I am new to Javascript and Web Development.

Thank You in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need 3 things:

1. an alt tag on each of the images that identifies what it is
2. the id of the correct answer, which corresponds to the alt tag of one of the images
3. a click function on each of the images that compares the Id of the image with the correct answer, and, if correct, shows an alert.

So something like this:

```
// Create the image element and set its src attribute
images[i] = document.createElement('img');
images[i].src = item.image;
images[i].alt = item.name;
images[i].onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target.alt == name_to_display)
    {
        alert('good job!');
    }
};
```

which should create an image tag that looks something like this:

```
<img alt="Brown Dog" src="/images/browndog.jpg" />
```

which when clicked on, compares the value of its alt tag with the saved name_to_display (which I'm assuming you meant to hold the value of the correct answer), and if the same, displays the alert. This should work if name_to_display is in the correct scope.

Comment: Thank You for the reply! What is the onclick calling? As I have tried this and it does nothig when any of the images are clicked? Thank You

Comment: and to confirm name_to_display is the word that displays on screen yes. Sorry i'm new to all this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: onclick is an event handler that attaches to the image. When a user clicks the image, the function should execute. The example I gave above was just that: an example. I did not test it. Try removing the if statement in the function: images[i].onclick = function(e) { alert('good job!') }; You should now see an alert on any of the images you click

Comment: the 'e' on function(e) is the event object that gets passed into this function by default. You can console.log(e) to see what's in it, but basically it contains an object with a bunch of dom information on what was clicked.

Comment: OK, edited my example and tested it. It will work, assuming that name_to_display is in scope. Become familiar with your error console -- it's your best friend when learning and debugging javascript errors.